# Build Map from String

Tags: dart

I use `Process.run` where I execute an `ldapsearch`. Then, I get a String from `stdout` that look like this:

```
user: demo
first-name: demo
picture: trewtrewtrwrwgr
grewgrwgrwgrewgrwegrwe==
```

Can I do simply a Map from existing method, or I have to make one ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert your entry :

```dart
String datas = '''user: demo
first-name: demo
picture: trewtrewtrwrwgr
grewgrwgrwgrewgrwegrwe==''';
final lines = datas.split('\n').fold([], (List<String> lines, line) {
  if (line.contains(':')) lines.add(line);
  // merge line that does not contain ":" with the previous
  else lines.add(lines.removeLast() + '\n' + line);
  return lines;
});
final m = new Map.fromIterable(lines.map((e) => e.split(':')),
    key: (e) => e[0].trim(),
    value: (e) => e[1].trim());
```

Never tried : you can also use [dartdap](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dartdap) (An LDAP Client Library for Dart).

Comment: It's already what I'm doing. But, `\n` it's not enough precise for the picture field. He take over 20 lines. And the LDAP library doesn't work for me.

Comment: Ooops I missed the multiline value. Sorry ! I have updated the answer to merge the lines. (I don't know if the '\n' is necessary, feel free to remove it)